# "_this is undefined" error when i want to use external "this" keyword

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, binding, export

In following example i received this error

> TypeError: _this is undefined

I tried many ways but couldn't find a way to fix the error, how can i solve it?

component_for_home_page.js

```
import { dispatch } from 'dispatch'

class Home extends PureComponent {
    componentDidMount() {
        dispatch('ADD_TEXT', 'Beep, Boop')

        // instead of following
            // this.props.dispatch({
            //     type: 'ADD_TEXT'
            //     text: 'Beep, Boop'
            // })
        //
    }

    render() {
        return (<p>{this.props.text}</p>)
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        ...state
    }
}

const connectedHomeComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(Home)

export {
    connectedHomeComponent
}
```

simplify_dispatch.js

```
const dispatch = (type, text) => {
    return this.props.dispatch({
        type,
        text
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `simplify_dispatch.js`, you're trying to access `this.props` but that is not in the correct context, since you want `this` to be from your `component_for_home_page`.  I'm not sure why you don't want to just use `this.props.dispatch(...)` but if you insist on following this approach, I would suggest passing a third argument to your function in `simplify_dispatch.js`, either `this.props` or `this.props.dispatch`

```
simplify_dispatch.js

const dispatch = (type, text, passedDispatch) => {
    return passedDispatch({
        type,
        text
    })
}

component_for_home_page.js

...
componentDidMount() {
   dispatch('ADD_TEXT', 'Beep, Boop', this.props.dispatch)
}
...
```

Comment: It is exactly what I wanted to learn, thank you so so so much.